# Integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}\ln(1+e^t) \, dt $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transcendental-equations, approximate-integration, transcendental-functions

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-t^2}\ln(1+e^t) \, dt $$

Hello everyone,i would like to know the result of the above integral and how to calculate or estimate it.

background and progress so far:(1)This is a transcendental integral,to calculate it,i used integration by Parts,but didn't work well.So i hope to find a way to give it an estimation or which is the better case,to calculate it in a closed form.
(2)According to the work done by Jingeon An,this integral is convergent and can be estimated through a scaling method.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you have some context (i.e. did it come from a book, etc)? That will determine whether we can expect it even has a nice closed form at all.

Comment: I actually didn't have much clue abou it.I think it's transcendental and i try to calculate it using integration by parts but seems doens''t work.So i want to know if there's other ways to calculate integral like that or give it an approximation.By the way,i'm not sure whether it's convergent,so your guys better check the convergence before calculating.

Comment: I think it by myself,not from books or other sources.

Comment: Given that the integrand is positive, consider that $\ln(1+e^t) < 1 + e^t$. Compare the integral with that.

Comment: @NinadMunshi. The result of the given integral is quite amazing.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici any tips on how to proceed? I would like to try the integral if you say it converges to a beautiful result.

Comment: @NinadMunshi. I do not think we can get any closed form result or whatever. Just computing the definite integral ... gives an amazing number. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found a closed form and an elegant solution as well! Unfortunately I cannot post it since the question is closed.

Comment: If you can edit your post with more details such as your attempts or any context behind this integral, I will vote to reopen. I have found an elegant solution to solve this integral exactly and would like to post it if appropriate.

Comment: @NinadMunshi. This is great (not surprising very much from you) ! Could you e-mail the result (my address is in my profile). Cheers :-)

Comment: @NinadMunshi.  This is great! So could you also e-mail me your answer?I'm the one who post the question,which is closed now,but i'm still looking forward to an answer

Comment: If you can edit your post, then yes I will paste my progress here. But there is no reason to deprive anyone else with this same integral question of the answer! :)

Comment: @NinadMunshi，okay,i'll try to make it open again.

Comment: @NinadMunshi,i've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

For the convergence, just find a function bigger than the given function and it's integral converges : Observe there exists $C>0$ such that $0<\ln(1+e^t)\leq Ct^2$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (check this claim by yourself). Then $$0\leq\bigg|\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\ln(1+e^t)dt\bigg|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\ln(1+e^t)dt\leq C\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}t^2<\infty$$ by Gaussian integral.

I believe calculating the exact result is more difficult, so if I can, I will add later.

Comment: nice estimation